# Help permanently mounting a Windows share on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Windows NTFS on my local domain. I can mount the share by going to "Places > Connect to a Server." I'd like to permanently mount my share to `/mnt/Quartz` which is a folder that exists under `mnt`. I have followed this guide, [MountWindowsSharePermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently), but I'm still getting a "`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on \\remote\quartz`" ... here's what I have setup:

/home/alfie/.smbcredentials:

```
username=windowsdomain/chum
password=myPassword
```

/etc/fstab:

```
//remote/quartz /mnt/quartz cifs credentials=/home/alfie/.smbcredentials
```

I save, run `sudo mount -a`, and I get the above error. Since I can mount the share through the GUI fine, I don't think there's a problem with the share. It must be simple, any ideas?

Comment: Well, I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with your thinking - I just replicated this locally and it worked.

Comment: Can you confirm that /sbin/mount.cifs exists?

Comment: Installed smbfs again and it worked great! If you want to make your comment an answer I'll mark it as best to give you the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that /sbin/mount.cifs exists.  Try reinstalling the smbfs package.